# breeze: combining web api entity with 3rd party wcf service

Tags: breeze

I use Web API to return a *Contrat* EF Entity along with the metadata.

The *Contract* entity has a PersonId property which holds a foreign key to a *Person* entity. 
That's where things get complicated.

In order to get the *Person* entity, I need to make a call to a WCF service. This service does not retrieve the entity using entity framekwork. In fact, the *Person* entity is stored in an Oracle database.

Then on the client side, I need to assign that *Person* entity to the *Contract* Entity. I suppose I need to extend the *Contract* model and add a property of type *Person*.

I have been through the Edmunds sample, which seems close to what I'm trying to do.

I don't intend to call the WCF service directly from the client. Instead I'm going to make a call to a GetPerson method in my WEB API service, which in turn will make a call to the WCF service.

So, my question is: since I've got access to the Web API service, should I try to return a IQueryable along with metadata (sounds difficult to me), or should I simply return JSON data and go the Edmunds sample's way ?

Which is going to be easier to implement ?

Answer (score 1):

The Edmunds example focuses on client-side queries to HTTP services that you do not control.

In this case, it sounds like you'd prefer to have everything happen on the server that you do control ... including any side-trips to a WCF service. That would be my preference too ... although I don't know the details that are necessary to make that judgment.

If I only need the related `Person` when I fetch a single `Contract`, I think I would have my Web API action method return a `Contract` graph composed entirely on the server (including the `Person` which I fetched on the server via the WCF Service).

But you may be thinking about the client who needs many `Contract` entities - each expanded with related `Person` entities - in a single call. Is this what you mean when you ask about putting `IQueryable` on the method?

If so, I'd still consider composing these entirely on the server - with side-trips to get the related `Person` objects - and then perhaps casting the resulting collection as an `IQueryable` so that the client could filter. Ugh. I suspect that `IQueryable` isn't wise; `IEnumerable` is probably better. You can still pass some filtering values to the Web API method (see `EntityQuery.withParameters`).

Comment: Thanks Ward for answering. I think you are right, doing everything on the server side is probably going to be easier. I have a question then. Suppose I create a custom EF datacontext. When I call the Contracts() method to query the Contract table, I should then make a call to my WCF service in order to populate the Person property of the Contract. Is the Metadata() method going to return metadata about the Person type ? If so, then everything should be just fine for me. Or do I still have to define the Person type on the client side ?